# How can I completing long task when app close?

Tags: android

I'm new in Android studio.

After the user close the app I trying to run a method that connect to some API using getInputStream, then get current params(those params update all the time) and POST it into user table database.

To know when the app close I use with onStop().

The problem is that I can't finish run the method completely because the app kill before the method finish the task.

In Swift I used in AppDelegate / applicationWillTerminate() and put sleep off 60 sec so i can finish the task.

Do you have some elegant idea to recognise that user kill the up and finish all the tasks in the method?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: "To know when the app close I use with onStop()" -- that does not really line up with "app close". "Do you have some elegant idea to recognise that user kill the up" -- use `ProcessLifecycleOwner`. "and finish all the tasks in the method?" -- that is not directly possible, as Android can terminate your process at any point once it is in the background. You could elect to schedule some work with `WorkManager`, though.

Answer (score 0):

if this task is urgent one and you want to run it immediately consider using foreground service else you can use workManager. for more information check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running)

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can use Android Services for doing such task. if your app perform specific task on specific situation e.g. doing something when connect with internet or connect charging then you need to use **work manager**. If you want to run the service forever then you need to implement foreground service.